# Get the id of the HTML element which triggered the tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display some dynamic content using bootstrap tooltip . For this i need to get the id of the current element ie.the element over which the mouse is currently positioned.

How do i obtain the id of this element.

The code i used is shown below. Excuse the poor coding , i'm just a beginner.

here id indicates the id of the HTML element.

```
function getData(id){
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.open('POST', '/bj',false)
req.send(id)
return req.responseText
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    title : getData(id)
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getData(id) {

  console.log(id);

  return id;
}

$(document).ready(function (){

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function (){

        $(this).tooltip({

            title: function (){

                return getData($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but its not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yez29vLo/2/  Btw. You must remove `title` attribute from all tooltip elements. `title` option is used only, when `title` attribute is not set.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips),

> If a function is given, it will be called with its `this` reference set to the element that the tooltip is attached to.

Therefore you could just pass an anonymous function and `this.id` would be the `id` of the element the tooltip is attached to when the function is invoked.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bzny4fgt/)

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    title: function () {
        return getData(this.id);
    }
});
```

---

As a side note, you could also listen to either of the `show.bs.tooltip`/`shown.bs.tooltip` events.

> [Bootstrap Docs - Tooltip Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)
>
> `show.bs.tooltip` - This event fires immediately when the `show` instance method is called.
>
> `shown.bs.tooltip` - This event is fired when the tooltip has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Within the event listeners, you could invoke your `getData` function and pass `this.id`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yez29vLo/)

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('show.bs.tooltip', function () {
  getData(this.id);
});
```

Comment: How to edit this code so as to display the tooltip with a title?

Comment: using  `this.id`  and just displaying the value from the getData function gives the value `undefined`.

Comment: @SATW What if you just try using the element's `id` directly (without the function) as I did in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/shh5p6p5/). It seems like your problem is related to the AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the inormation provided, don't know why it didnt work.